# Two Dotnet Core projects with different versions of same package problem

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package, encapsulation

Package N (Community) is available via Nuget.

**Project A** uses Package N (Community), 2.3.0 extensively.

Package N (Pro), version 2.5.0 has a single required feature not available in the Community version, but cannot be used in place of the Community version because current functionality breaks in significant ways.

My proposed solution was to create **Project B** that uses Package N (Pro). **Project B** makes the required function available through an interface.

**Project A** can then use **Project B** as a Package Reference.

I thought this would encapsulate **Project B**'s use of the Pro Version of Package N and keep it separate from **Project A**.

However, after adding the reference to **Project B** in **Project A**, **Project A** now tries to use the Pro Version of Package N that is only added as a package reference in
**Project B**.

Is there a way to keep the packages used by **Project B** encapsulated from anything that uses it?